# AngularJs "Blade Routing"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-include

How can a "Blade routing" as from the azure portal are created with angular ?
The only way I see is current with ngRepeat and ngInclude .

Is this a good way ? or is there a better one?

[image]

Comment: you could go for `angular-ui-router`, where you can have multiple named view based on `route`

Comment: ui router I already know .
However, this represents my knowledge not functionality that is needed .
an example. in the app list you open an app , and then the settings or users .
at another point , the server list and then the apps ... and always adds a new blade .

Comment: the UI router would have a UI-View collection deploy which can be expanded and reduced on demand .